# compare R packages missForest and Hmisc performance

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation

I am trying to compare the performance of 2 R packages, missForest and Hmisc performace in dealing with missing value, when there are more than 50% missing values.

I got testing data in this way:

```
data("iris")
library(missForest)
iris.mis <- prodNA(iris, noNA = 0.6)
summary(iris.mis)

mis1 <- iris.mis
mis2 <- iris.mis
```

In missForest, it has `mixError()` method which allows you to compare the imputation accuracy with the original data.

```
# using missForest
missForest_imputed <- missForest(mis1, ntree = 100)
missForest_error <- mixError(missForest_imputed$ximp, mis1, iris)
dim(missForest_imputed$ximp)
missForest_error
```

Hmisc does not have `mixError()` method, I am using its powerful `aregImpute()` to do the imputation, like this:

```
# using Hmisc
library(Hmisc)
hmisc_imputed <- aregImpute(~Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width + Species, 
                        data = mis2, n.impute = 1)
```

I was hoping to convert the imputed results into a format like `missForest_imputed$ximp`, so that I can use `mixError()` method. The problem is, in `aregImpute()`, no matter I tried `n.impute = 1` or `n.impute = 5`, I cannot have 150 values for each feature like the original data iris... And the number of values in each feature is also different....

So, is there any way to compare the performance of missForest and Hmisc in dealing with missing values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Part 1

`Hmisc::aregImpute` returns the imputed values. For your object named `hmisc_imputed`, they can be found in `hmisc_imputed$imputed`. However, the `imputed` object is a list for each dimension.

If you wish to *recreate* the equivalent of `missForest_imputed$ximp`, you have to do it yourself. To do so, we can use the fact that:

```
all.equal(as.integer(attr(xx$Sepal.Length, "dimnames")[[1]]), which(is.na(iris.mis$Sepal.Length))) ## returns true
```

Which I do here:

```
check_missing <- function(x, hmisc) {
  return(all.equal(which(is.na(x)), as.integer(attr(hmisc, "dimnames")[[1]])))
}

get_level_text <- function(val, lvls) {
  return(lvls[val])
}

convert <- function(miss_dat, hmisc) {
  m_p <- ncol(miss_dat)
  h_p <- length(hmisc)
  if (m_p != h_p) stop("miss_dat and hmisc must have the same number of variables")
  # assume matches for all if 1 matches
  if (!check_missing(miss_dat[[1]], hmisc[[1]]))
    stop("missing data an imputed data do not match")

  for (i in 1:m_p) {
    i_factor <- is.factor(miss_dat[[i]])
    if (!i_factor) {miss_dat[[i]][which(is.na(miss_dat[[i]]))] <- hmisc[[i]]}
    else {
      levels_i <- levels(miss_dat[[i]])
      miss_dat[[i]] <- as.character(miss_dat[[i]])
      miss_dat[[i]][which(is.na(miss_dat[[i]]))] <- sapply(hmisc[[i]], get_level_text, lvls= levels_i)
      miss_dat[[i]] <- factor(miss_dat[[i]])
    }
  }
  return(miss_dat)
}

iris.mis2 <- convert(iris.mis, hmisc_imputed$imputed)
```

#### Part 2

`mixError` uses RMSE to calculate error-rates, `?mixError`:

> **Value** imputation error. In case of continuous variables only this is the normalized root mean squared error (NRMSE, see 'help(missForest)' for further details). In case of categorical variables onlty this is the proportion of falsely classified entries (PFC). In case of mixed-type variables both error measures are supplied.

To do this on your object from "Part 1" [`iris.mis2`], you just need to use the `nrmse` function, which is provided in `library(missForest)`.

Comment: This is really great!! Thank you very much Alex, I have learned a lot form your R code! For Part 2, I think PFC is still needed because Species is factor. Anyway, thank you very much!!